# FIlter 2d array using 1d boolean array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have two numpy arrays.

```
x = [[1,2], [3,4], [5,6]]
y = [True, False, True]
```

I'd like to get the element of `X` of which corresponding element of `y` is `True`:

```
filtered_x = filter(x,y)
print(filtered_x) # [[1,2], [5,6]] should be shown.
```

I've tried `np.extract`, but it seems work only when `x` is 1d array. How do I extract the elements of `x` corresponding value of `y` is `True`?

Comment: x[y]. It's called boolean indexing.

Comment: You can try using a list comprehension like `[val for val in x if y[x.index(val)]]`. Simple and elegant.

Comment: @AsadMoosvi and slower than numpy built in functions, and also does not return a np.array...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just use [boolean indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing):

```
>>> import numpy as np

>>> x = np.array([[1,2], [3,4], [5,6]])
>>> y = np.array([True, False, True])
>>> x[y]   # or "x[y, :]" because the boolean array is applied to the first dimension (in this case the "rows")
array([[1, 2],
       [5, 6]])
```

And in case you want to apply it on the columns instead of the rows:

```
>>> x = np.array([[1,2], [3,4], [5,6]])
>>> y = np.array([True, False])
>>> x[:, y]  # boolean array is applied to the second dimension (in this case the "columns")
array([[1],
       [3],
       [5]])
```

Comment: For consistency and clarity, I prefer x[y, :] and x[:, y]

Comment: I tend to prefer to omit trailing `, :` because it's more to type and the result doesn't differ if I include them or omit them. But I can see where it's easier to understand. :)

Answer (score 0):

`l=[x[i]  for i in range(0,len(y)) if y[i]]`  this will do it.